# ATTiny204 accurate delay with correct fuses and F_CPU

Tags: microcontroller, avr, attiny

So I worked with an ATTiny for the first time today and I was quite different from my regular Arduino / ESP8266 programming.

When testing the Blink script I noticed that the delays weren't correct at all.
I think I understand that I have to set the Clock Frequency Fuse and some Symbols correctly in order to have accurate delays.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/delay.h>

#define F_CPU   20000000UL

int main(void)
{

  PORTA.DIR |= PIN4_bm;

  while (1) {
    PORTA.OUT |= PIN4_bm;
    _delay_ms(1000);
    PORTA.OUT &= ~PIN4_bm;
    _delay_ms(1000);
  }
}
```

Platformio.ini (Inluding fuses):

```
[env:ATtiny204]
platform = atmelmegaavr
board = ATtiny204
framework = arduino
board_fuses.osccfg = 0x2
board_build.f_cpu = 20000000L
board_fuses.MCLKCTRLB.PEN = 0x00

upload_flags =  
    -c$UPLOAD_PORT
upload_command = pyupdi $UPLOAD_FLAGS -f $SOURCE -d attiny204 -v
```

Readout of the set fuses:

```
Device info: {'family': 'tinyAVR', 'nvm': 'P:0', 'ocd': 'D:0', 'osc': '3', 'device_id': '1E9122', 'device_rev': '0.1'}
    Fuse:Value
    0:0x00    
    1:0x00    
    2:0x02    
    3:0xFF    
    4:0x00    
    5:0xF6    
    6:0x07    
    7:0x00 
    8:0x00 
    9:0xFF 
    10:0xC5
```

`osccfg = 0x2` should set the clock to 20MHz, which I also set in `F_CPU 20000000UL` correctly. At least I think that.
The delays are more like 4s in reality.
How do I fix that?

I'm unsing PlatformIO as my IDE.
Clock source is Internal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the MCLKCTRLB.PEN (prescaler enable) bit to zero when the controller starts up (at the start of your main function). Otherwise the internal clock prescaler is active, which divides the clock by 6 by default.

The [datasheet's](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/50002687a.pdf) section on the clock controller (section 10) explains this. Note that you have to follow a special unlock procedure to change this register.

```
int main(void) {
    CPU_CCP = CCP_IOREG_gc; //Unlock the IO config registers for writing
    CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLB = 0;  //Disable the prescaler
    ...
```

Comment: I set the 0x01 Register MCLKCTRLB to 0x00. This also set the PEN bit to 0, I also confirmed the fuses. However the delay is still wrong. Or do I get it all wrong and the Register has to be set at runtime in the script?

Comment: Could you please update your question with the new code?

Comment: Sure. I added the fuses read from the attiny

Comment: Ah... I see your mistake now. MCLKCTRLB is not a fuse register, it's a peripheral register that your C code has to set. Fuse register 0x1 controls the brown-out detector. I've updated my answer to include example code on how to change MCLKCTRLB.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but if you are using the Arduino IDE to program the board, be sure to select the correct clock speed in the IDE too (and burn the bootloader after changing it, not sure if this helps in this case). Even if you are using another IDE, it's worth a try.

Comment: I'm using PlatformIO and programming via a USB to Serial with pyupdi. Setting this up in the Arduino IDE would be some extra work and I don't use the Arduino IDE. Can I do this without it too?

Comment: In that case I dont think my answer would help. In the Arduino IDE (with the megatinycore extension) you can select the chip frequency easily, and you don't have to write code to set fuses, but this does not apply to your example.